# "but not" at the end of the sentence

Tags: meaning

After reading [this](https://medium.com/@nettlefish/the-science-of-the-pendulum-sun-e7116070d4ce) article, there are two sentences that I can't understand:

> Their world is magically built to be like ours but not. So their sun,
> their moon, their seasons would be like ours but not.

If they don't have *but not* at the end, I can understand. I don't know what is the meaning of *but not* here. I'm very confused, *but not*? not what?

Comment: Like ours (in some ways), but not like ours (in other ways).

Comment: their seasons would be ***like*** our seasons, but they would not actually ***be*** our seasons (there would be some noticeable differences). But the cited example is deliberately "quirky" phrasing which you probably shouldn't ever copy yourself.

Comment: There should be a comma before the final phrase "but not".

Comment: It's likely up to interpretation. I interpret this to mean "their sun looks like ours, but isn't like ours". In the paragraph before, she talks about sun hanging like a pendulum, so it would look like our Sun from the planet's surface, but it wouldn't involve planetary revolution like Earth and Sun.

Comment: It's not really "valid" syntax in the first place, which is why there's some scope for "parsing" it in different ways. Personally, I interpret that final ***not*** as negating preceding ***be***, not ***like*** - that's to say they ***are*** like ours, but ***are not*** [actually] ours. As opposed to ***not*** negating the word ***like*** itself, which would give the somewhat paradoxical assertion *they **are like** ours AND they **are not like** ours*.